# Site.com Publisher User (feature license) : is it required for publishing a Community using Site.com Studio?

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I can easily publish a community built with Site.com studio in a developer org environment.

I'm now trying to do the same thing working for a customer in an Enterprise Org, but I actually cannot publish the Site from the Sandbox environment (I can publish the community, but I don't see the Publish button in the site.com Studio).
 Also, even if I set up the public access, the community seems to be not reachable from the Internet. So I'm wondering about some doubt, i.e.,

1) Do I need some particular license for publishing sites (e.g. Site.com Publisher User feature license)
2) Maybe you cannot publish sites from a sanbox?

I found different answer but some of them are incompatible each other.

This link seems to clearly explain that no license are required for this accomplishment : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181865&language=en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are separate feature license for site.com. Please see screen shot below:

[image]

When you go to user detail view, there are few checkbox which includes "Site.com" publisher User" check box. It consumes one license if you check it, otherwise you will get exception if there is no license.

Following list shows all feature licenses:

[image]

---

You can publish a site from sandbox (if you have license) as well but it will have different URL than Production. But from Winter '14 publishing site no more available.

> Each community has one associated Site.com site that lets you add
>   custom, branded pages to your community. Communities users with the
>   “Create and Set Up Communities” permission automatically have full
>   site administrator access to a community’s Site.com site. To let
>   Communities users without the permission edit the site, you must
>   purchase and assign either a Site.com Publisher or a Site.com
>   Contributor feature license, and assign a user role at the site level.

Comment: So, what about this link explanation? It seems to be incompatible with your answer  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181865&language=en_US

Comment: This links says that if you are using community then you don't need that particular license because site.com pages are then published within the URL of community. They become part of community. @ToninoTripodi

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193345&language=en_US

Comment: @ToninoTripodi updated the answer as per the provided link.

Comment: So, the question now could be : how to test Site.com (if not in "preview" mode) in sandbox? This way I only could build my pages and then export to prod environment... and so, at this point, maybe it's better to develop directly in prod? Sandobox does not let me do anything but build..

Comment: @TininoTripodi In my scenario we make changes on site directly in prod if they can be. On large development we develop on sandbox and export to production. In sandbox there must be preview button. Are you sure? In production until you don't publish no change will go live.